# How to pad strings of different lengths with '----' so that in the end all strings will have the same length?

Tags: c++, string, padding

Im writing a Log report for n tests im running on my code. The output goes into a log which looks something like this:

```
test subject number 12 had result 0.12334 ------> PASSED!!!
test subject number 1 had result 56 ------> PASSED!!!
test subject number 123 had result 2 ------> FAILED!!!
```

and so on.

I would like that the `PASSED` or `FAILED` statement would be aligned with each other regardless of the length of the string that came before them, it should look like this:

```
test subject number 12 had result 0.12334 ------> PASSED!!!
test subject number 1 had result 56 ------------> PASSED!!!
test subject number 123 had result 2 -----------> FAILED!!!
```

I have this function that pads the `--->` arrows and `PASSED` or `FAILED` statement but it doesn't do the job right:

```
void AddPassedOrFailed(std::string& LogMessage, bool passed)
    {
        int initial_size = LogMEssage.size();
        for ( int i = initial_size ; i < 200 - initial_size ; i ++)
        {
            if (i == 200 - initial_size -1)
                LogMessage += (passed ? "> PASSED!!! ": "> FAILED!!!");
            else
                LogMessage += "-";
        }
        LogMessage +="\n";
    }
```

`LogMessage` is one line like this: `"test subject number 12 had result 0.12334 "`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Seems like a line like `while(LogMessage.size() < 60) LogMessage += '-';` would do most of the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always a good investment of time to spend browsing your favorite C++ reference manual. Where, for example, one can learn about very useful `std::string` overloads. Such as the two argument version of `resize()`:

```
void AddPassedOrFailed(std::string& LogMessage, bool passed)
{
     LogMessage.resize(200, '-');
     LogMessage += (passed ? "> PASSED!!!\n": "> FAILED!!!\n");
}
```